# Catastrophic error with ifort when allocating parametric declared type within a declared type

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

Please consider following code

```
  module t_test
     implicit none

     type ttt(tsize)
        integer, len :: tsize
        real x(tsize)
     end type ttt



  type :: t_rndom_diameter(t_rsize,t_csize)
      integer, len :: t_rsize,t_csize
      real :: x(t_rsize,t_csize)
     type(ttt(tsize=:)), allocatable :: test_type
  end type t_rndom_diameter




  end module t_test


  program p_test
  USE t_test
  implicit none

  type(t_rndom_diameter(t_rsize=3,t_csize=3)) :: gdad

  allocate(gdad% ttt(tsize=10) ::  gdad % test_type)


  end program
```

it gives me a catastrophic error without mentioning what the error is:

```
catastrophic error: **Internal compiler error: segmentation violation signal raised** Please
report this error along with the circumstances in which it occurred in a Software Problem
Report.  Note: File and line given may not be explicit cause of this error.
```

However, I know what triggers this error, namely: `allocate(gdad% ttt(tsize=10) :: gdad% test_type)`

What does this mean?

I also tried without `gdad`, i.e. `allocate(gdad% ttt(tsize=10) :: test_type)`

Comment: As the error message states, this is an error in the compiler.  This should be reported to Intel so it can be fixed.  Also, your code is faulty: what are you trying to do with that allocation?  It is not the correct syntax, but without knowing what you intend I can't say how to correct it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not installed gfortran on my laptop although would be very keen to have tried compiling with that to see if the error only relates to `ifort`

Comment: @francescalus could you be more specific about what part of the allocation is faulty

Comment: In an allocate statement the thing before the `::` must be a type specifier.`gdad% ttt(tsize=10)` isn't one.

Comment: I am not getting you 100%. How would you have declared it?

Comment: Perhaps you just mean `ttt(10)` (which is a type specifier), rather than `gdad%ttt(10)`?

Comment: Well that solved the problem I think ! Thanks

Comment: For the record, gfortran issues an error message for the invalid code.  If you haven't done so, send a problem report to Intel.

Comment: I will  - thanks for the update on gfortran!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, an "internal compiler error" relates to a bug in the compiler.  This is something to report to the compiler vendor.

However, in this case it would be a low priority problem: the code you are attempting to compile is invalid.  As noted, the problematic line is

```
allocate(gdad% ttt(tsize=10) ::  gdad % test_type)
```

This is invalid because this form of the `allocate` statement requires a type specifier on the left-hand side.  `gdad%ttt(10)` is not such a thing.  The correct statement would be

```
allocate(ttt(tsize=10) ::  gdad % test_type)
```